# Label a feature based on Intersection with another feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, mxd, maplex

In Arcmap, I have a feature class that I want to label but only where there is NO intersection with another feature class in my MXD. I know one strategy would be to populate a field based on a spatial query with the other feature class first using geoprocessing but thats not really an option. Is it possible to do this in the SQL Label Query in Label Manager or a Python Expression? My data is stored in a GDB

Comment: What have you tried?  Why is another field not an option?  Have you tried using annotation and some kind of spatial query (I'm not sure if that's even possible)